# Robot keys are not working in VM when I close the connection

Tags: java, selenium, virtual-machine, edit

We are using selenium-java for automation and I am facing an issue with robot keys in VM. When I am executing code with a connection to VM open, robot keys are working fine. But if I kick-start the execution and close the VM connection, it is failing.

I am using below code:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(250);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);          
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Is there a way to overcome the issue?

Comment: What is the error you see in logs?

Comment: @eduPeeth  There is no error displayed. My script is simply failing at that point to perform actions using robot keys.

Comment: That is the drawback of using Robot class, for it to work properly your browser needs to be in focus all the time.